# убрать непересекающиеся значения из векторов c++

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Предположим, есть 3 вектора следующего вида (значения в них не повторяются, и они уже отсортированы):

```
std::vector<std::pair<int,string>> vector;
```

Каждый содержит следующие значения:

```
1 вектор: {(1,a),(2,b),(3,c)};
2 вектор: {(1,k),(5,q),(4,r)};
3 вектор: {(1,e),(6,d),(7,v)};
```

Необходимо оставить в каждом из векторов только пересекающиеся значение, т.е, должно остаться:

```
в 1 векторе:{(1,a)};
во 2 векторе {(1,k)};
в 3 векторе {(1,e)};
```

Как это можно сделать?

Comment: Вам нужен [std::set_intersection](http://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_intersection) и правильный компаратор для Ваших данных

Comment: @KoVadim Немного не то: ему нужно *удалить* из векторов...

Comment: если так не сможет, тогда циклы. Но элементы не удалять, а получить новые и подменить потом старые. В таком случае задача решается проще.

Comment: Кстати, а что делать, если, скажем, в первом векторе есть еще `(1,z)`? Оставлять или удалять? А если во втором - `(2,q)` - или нужны только те, что есть во всех трех?

Comment: @Harry, Только те, что есть во всех трех. Повторяющихся значений в векторах нет. Что касается std::set_intersection, то я о нем знаю. Но, если использовать его, я так понимаю, нужно для первого вектора относительно всех остальных, для второго, относительно всех остальных... и т.д, правильно?

Comment: хотя нет, я так понимаю можно применить set_intersection к первому вектору 2 раза: со вторым вектором, и получившийся вектор с третьим. Затем, получив итоговый вектор, который содержит пересечения со всеми остальными,  применить его для 2 и 3 вектора...

Comment: Да, но что-то у меня ощущение, что тогда проще написать руками :) Раз уж они отсортированы, поочередно переходит там, где наименьший из трех, к следующему элементу. Если все три равны - переходим к следующему во всех трех. Если вектора не длинные, или если это не вектора, а, скажем, `list` - ну, с быстрым удалением спереди - то вполне работоспособно может быть...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно найти пары общие для всех векторов (`common_pairs`), а затем убрать пары из каждого вектора, которые не принадлежат пересечению, используя [`set_intersection()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_intersection):

```
#include <algorithm> // set_intersection
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator> // back_inserter
#include <string>
#include <type_traits> // remove_reference
#include <utility> // pair
#include <vector>    

int main()
{
  using namespace std;
  typedef vector<pair<int, string>> V;
  V seqs[] = {
    {{1, "a"}, {2, "b"}, {3, "c"}},
    {{1, "k"}, {5, "q"}, {4, "r"}},
    {{1, "e"}, {6, "d"}, {7, "v"}},
  };

  // find intersection of k vectors
  V common_pairs;
  auto less_first = [](auto a, auto b) { return a.first < b.first; };
  set_intersectionk(begin(seqs), end(seqs), back_inserter(common_pairs),
                    less_first);

  // remove pairs that are not in the intersection
  for (auto&& v : seqs) {
    V temp;
    set_intersection(begin(v), end(v), begin(common_pairs), end(common_pairs),
                     back_inserter(temp), less_first);
    v.swap(temp);
  }

  // print results
  for (auto&& v : seqs) {
    for (auto&& p : v)
      cout << "(" << p.first << ", " << p.second << ") ";
    cout << endl;
  }
}
```

Пример:

```
$ g++ -std=c++14 *.cc && ./a.out
(1, a) 
(1, k) 
(1, e)
```

Где `set_intersectionk()` просто попарно находит пересечение векторов:

```
/// Find common elements among collections given in [first, last) range.
template<class InputIt, class OutIt, class Compare>
OutIt set_intersectionk(InputIt first, InputIt last, OutIt out, Compare comp)
{
  if (first == last) // no collections
    return out;

  typedef std::vector<std::remove_reference_t<decltype(*begin(*first))>> V;
  V intersection(begin(*first), end(*first));
  for (++first; first != last; ++first) {
    V temp;
    temp.swap(intersection);
    std::set_intersection(std::begin(*first), std::end(*first),
                          std::begin(temp), std::end(temp),
                          std::back_inserter(intersection),
                          comp);
  }
  return std::copy(begin(intersection), end(intersection), out);
}
```

Входные коллекции не обязаны быть векторами. С точки зрения худшего случая (`k` одинаковых коллекций), временная сложность алгоритма уже оптимальна `O(k*n)`. Если пересечение заметно меньше, то можно улучшить время исполнения, если не смотреть на каждый (отличающийся) элемент, к примеру, используя [поиск удвоением](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_search), предложенный [в обсуждении похожего вопроса](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25505868/the-intersection-of-multiple-sorted-arrays#comment39843093_25506213) для реализации `set_intersection()`:

```
/// Return the first iterator such that !comp(*it, key)
template<class It,
         class K = typename std::iterator_traits<It>::value_type,
         class Compare = std::less<K> >
It doubling_lower_bound(It first, It last, K key, Compare comp = {})
{
  typename std::iterator_traits<It>::difference_type upper_bound = 1,
    count = std::distance(first, last);
  while (upper_bound < count && comp(*std::next(first, upper_bound), key))
    upper_bound *= 2;
  return std::lower_bound(std::next(first, upper_bound / 2),
                          std::next(first, std::min(upper_bound, count)),
                          key, comp);
}

template<class It1, class It2, class OutIt, class Compare>
OutIt set_intersection(It1 first1, It1 last1, It2 first2, It2 last2,
                       OutIt out, Compare comp)
{
  for ( ; first2 != last2; ++first2) {
    first1 = doubling_lower_bound(first1, last1, *first2, comp);
    if (first1 == last1)
      break; // all(first1s) < *first2 <= all(first2s)
    first2 = doubling_lower_bound(first2, last2, *first1, comp);
    if (first2 == last2)
      break; // all(first2s) < *first1 <= all(first1s)
    *out++ = *first1++; // !(a < b) && !(b < a)  <=>  a == b
  }
  return out;
}
```

Comment: помечу ваше решение как правильное. оно, всё-таки, поинтереснее)

Answer (score 1):

ну, в общем, как-то так. за оптимальность не отвечаю, но на 4 векторах размерами около 100 тыс. считает быстро (вектора должны быть заранее отсортированы)

```
void setIntersectionData(std::vector<std::vector<std::pair<int,string>>>& data)
    {
        if(data.size()==1)
        {
            return;
        }

        /*формируем первый вектор, как вектор без непересекающимеся значениями относительно остальных*/
        for(int i=1;i<data.size();i++)
        {
            std::vector<std::pair<int,string>> intersectedData;// вектор, который будет содержать непересекающиеся значения, его будем присваивать первому вектору
            std::set_intersection (data[0].begin(), data[0].end(), data[i].begin(), data[i].end(),std::back_inserter(intersectedData),
                    [](const auto& a, const auto& b){return a.first<b.first;});
            data[0]=std::move(intersectedData);
        }
       /*убираем непересекающиеся значения из остальных векторов*/
        for(int i=1;i<data.size();i++)
        {
            std::vector<std::pair<int,string>> intersectedData;// вектор, который будет содержать непересекающиеся значения, его будем присваивать оставшимся векторам
            std::set_intersection (data[i].begin(), data[i].end(), data[0].begin(), data[0].end(),std::back_inserter(intersectedData),
                    [](const auto& a, const auto& b){return a.first<b.first});
            data[i]=std::move(intersectedData);
        }
    }
```

Comment: работает ли это, если вектора, которые позже идут, меньшее пересечение образуют? К примеру, если последний вектор не содержал бы `(1,e)` пары, то сделает ли ваше решение все вектора пустыми?

Comment: @jfs, вы знаете ответ, или действительно спрашиваете? ну, если я ничего не упустил, то отсутствие (1,e) пары сделает вектор data[0] в первом цикле пустым. а применение его затем к оставшимся векторам сделает пустыми и их...

Comment: Разобрался: у вас data[0] выполняет роль common_pairs в моём коде.